# Published content not displaying, getting not found message

Tags: posts

I am posting data in wordpress but after click on public it is showing

> This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?
>   It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or one of the links below, can help.

I dont have any idea how to resolve this. I am using wordpress4.1
Screenshots

[image]

After click on publish

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach some screenshot so we can have an idea of your issue?

Comment: You will need to give more info on this. From what you have given, I can only speculate that you are using custom post types which is excluded from the main query, and this will lead to the failure you are seeing visiting your homepage

Comment: @PieterGoosen ,@jepser Please see the edit

Comment: That does not help at all. My question is, are you using custom post types? If not, then it is impossible to say what is causing this, and might be theme related, something in the region of a custom filter, bad template file ...

Comment: NO  not using custom post types

Comment: Last thing I done was updated wp from 4 to 4.1 and installed few plugin now I removed plugin but wp is 4.1. Is there any way to debug this

Comment: Add wp_reset_query() before your loop.

Comment: @FatihSARI I am not using any custome query where to use it I am not getting

Comment: Hard to say but this might be too localized? Few classical things to test: Did you try the default theme? Without plugins? And maybe test it without permalinks (example.tld?p=123) ? Anything strange in your .htaccess file? Did you check the error files? Did you remember to use WP_DEBUG? Hopefully you're testing this on a dev install and also remember to backup your live site before anything.

Comment: I love wordpress but I dont know php. Could you please also tell me the steps to do

Comment: You write that the not found message appears after pressing "Publish". Do you mean it appears immediately after this or do you mean after publishing and then clicking on "View Post"? Is the Post saved at all? What happens when saving as draft?

Comment: On click on publish it is showing next page error

Answer (score 1):

Please reset your permalink. Go to `http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and just click `Save Changes` button.

**Edited:**
Try these steps:

1. Make sure the homepage exists. Go to `Settings > Reading options`, see which page is used for homepage and check this page's status.
2. Update WordPress. Keep backup before you proceed.
3. Check each of the plugins. Deactivate and re-activate one by one and see what happens.
4. It may happen that **modSecuriy process is checking the wp-admin and
   the input of data**. Edit the modsecurity whitelist-

`vi /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2/whitelist.conf`

Add this code

`<LocationMatch "/wp-admin/*">
  SecRuleEngine Off
</LocationMatch>`

then restart apache. `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

Comment: Not working I have selected(default) Post name  http://example.com/sample-post/ and save change

Comment: I have edited my answer. Did you check it?

Comment: I have done upto step 3 then tried to post again same problem. I am using cpanel where how to use 4 and above step i am not getting

Comment: Simple updating of permalinks worked for me! (Clicking "Save Changes")

Answer (score 1):

This is can be because of following reasons.

1.Premalink problem.
Go to settings -> permalinks and set to default. save and check if post is now showing.
If its working fine then reset premalink structure to desired one (like postname), save and check.

2.rewrite problem in .htaccess file
Check if url is re-written in htaccess file or if it is then it rewrite rule is proper.

3.Url rewrite from functions.php file
Check if urls are overridden in function.php file.

4.Post is in draft or not set to public

Comment: 1 done not working for 2 what to check in .htaccess file

Comment: can it see stores error log anywhere??

Comment: What is your current permalink structure ? Can you post site url and post url that is giving 404 ?

Comment: I am using  Post name as default and my site name is www.ebhor.com

Comment: Did you check post status? it should be published. I had a look on screenshot above and found that post is in draft.

Answer (score 0):

Goto settings -> permalinks option and change the common settings. Check the post again.

If this does not work then check the .htaccess file.

Comment: what to check in .htaaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable `WP_Debug` ?

1. Go to File Manager.
2. Locate the `wp-config.php` file for your WordPress website.
3. Click Edit for the `wp-config.php` file.
4. To enable `WP_Debug`, add the following code to the end of the file:

   ```
   /**
   * WordPress Debugging
   *
   * Set to "true" to enable wp_debug. Set to "false" to disable.
   * Do not include quotes when setting to "true" or "false".
   */
   define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
   ```

Comment: Initially not enabled just done it. Where it will show debug

Comment: it will show you the errors & warnings in the website (if you haven't use any error suppressing )

Comment: Well I am unable to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well i had something similar and i was banging my head why when i was editing an existing post it was fine but when i was doing one on my own it was simple ... " not found "
The "key" is the slug, since i am from Greece , using Greek letters for my posts and subsequently the slug was "getting" the Greek heading it would simply won't work.
Changing slug to Latin letters was the key to "success"